# How does a mapping of an individual relationship in code first become?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, mapping

These are my classes.

```
public class Teacher
{
    public Teacher()
    {
        this.isPassive = false;
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> LessonID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }

}

public class Lesson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Below are the codes I mapped.

```
public TeacherMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.ID).Property(t => t.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        //Relationship            
        HasOptional(t => t.Lesson)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.LessonID);
    }
```

These are my classes and teacher classes. A teacher should have a lesson and a lesson must have a teacher. How should I do this mapping?

Comment: what is relation between teacher and lesson , one lesson can have many teacher?

Comment: This fiction will also be a lesson from a teacher. And one lesson will be a teacher. So the relationship must be one.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a relation one to many , for example a lesson can have one or many teacher you can use this code :

```
    public class Teacher
    {
        public Teacher()
        {
            this.isPassive = false;
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> LessonID { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Teachers")]
        [ForeignKey("LessonID")]
        public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }

    }

    public class Lesson
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Lesson")]
        public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set;}

    }
```

for this secenario you dont need use fluent api.

UPDATE :

for one to one relation :

```
    public class Teacher
    {
        public Teacher()
        {
            this.isPassive = false;
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }

    }

    public class Lesson
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("Teacher")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }


        public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set;}

    }
```

For more information see [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) .

Comment: I know that normally it is. But in the project that was given to me, they wanted me to make 1 to 1 relationship. How will Mapping work?

Comment: [Key, ForeignKey ("Student")]

Why is there a student here? I can give you what I want as a name, right?